# What is the difference in these two calls?

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs

I cannot for the life of my figure out what is going on.

I have these two calls, this one works and logs exactly what I expect.

```
getEmployeeId() {
    fetch(API_URL + `/clients/all`)
      .then((res) => {
        if (!res.ok) {
          throw new Error();
        }
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
      });
  }
```

This one, logs an empty array. The only difference in the fetch path.

```
getEmployeeId() {
    fetch(API_URL + `/interviews/getEmployeeId`)
      .then((res) => {
        if (!res.ok) {
          throw new Error();
        }
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
      });
  }
```

Which of course makes me think then that the issue must be in the API routes.
This one works:

```
app.get('/clients/all', function (req, res) {
    connection.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM clients", function (error, results) {
            // If some error occurs, we throw an error.
            if (error) throw error;
            console.log(results);
            res.json(results);
        });
        connection.release();
    });
});
```

This one does not:

```
app.get("/interviews/getEmployeeId", function (req, res) {
  connection.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM audit_interview", function (error, results) {
      if (error) throw error;
      console.log(results);
      res.json(results);
    });
    connection.release();
  });
});
```

The query calls for both of them work as expected in mySql Workbench.  Anyone spot the problem?

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but you have double quotes in the one that doesn't work.

Comment: Unfortunately, not that easy.  I changed it to match the other, and still doesn't work.  I have literally cut & paste the code now so that everything other than the path is the same, and still doesn't work.  Ugh...

Comment: I'm not sure what `connection` is exactly but it seems like you might have a race condition since you are calling `.release` before the callback is executed with the results.

Comment: Well it's the oddest thing, because if I simply change the fetch path to any of my other routes, it works fine... and they're all setup the same.  Including the .release.

connection is creating my connection to the database the get the data, and release is freeing that connection back up.

Comment: Are you sure that there are entries in the `audit_interview` table, and that the code you have shared is what is actually running?

Comment: Yes, there are 35 of them.  The query works in Sql workbench just fine.  I'm stumped.

Comment: Did you try `connection.release();` after you get the results (inside that callback)? because it could be a timing issue because JS is Async.

Comment: I did, and no difference, not to mention I have 10 other routes that are all the same setup, and this is the only one that doesn't work.  

I have also just tried typing in the routes in the browser. I gave it the same query as another one that works. All the others give me the data I expect, but this route gives me: []

So it must be something in the route... but I don't understand because it is the exact same code, cut & paste, except changing the route path.  Even when I use the query from one that works... all I get is [].

Comment: Actually... the frustrating thing is that I just changed the name of the path to something else and it works. Apparently I can't use the word interviews???

Comment: Is it possible that you have another endpoint like `/interviews/:id`, which is taking precedence over this one?

Comment: Ah,..... you are exactly right.... I knew it would be something simple like that I was missing.